# Why am I getting an “Office Update Required” required message even though I have already upgraded Microsoft Office?

Tags: macos

I am using a MacBook Pro with MacOS Big Sur (11.1). I have updated Office Suite to 16.44 20121301. Now I am left with the previous version of Microsoft Word 16.16 20101200 within Microsoft AutoUpdate (4.30) with the message, “Office Update Required.” But Office is already updated?

How do I remove this please?